# Copy blob from one directory into another in same container Azure Storage

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

### Problem

I am trying to copy the blob from one directory and past into other directory and the delete the blob from source. I already tried the below code but not copy and past into another folder is done but delete operation works.

### Code

```
var cred = new StorageCredentials("storageName", "Key");
var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = client.GetContainerReference("containerName");
CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("folder/test.jpg");

//this doesn't work
sourceBlob.StartCopyAsync(new Uri("destination url"));
//this works
sourceBlob.DeleteAsync();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You need to `await` as Igor mentioned.
- `StartCopyAsync` is just a method to "start" copy process, you still need to monitor the copy state before deleting the blob. Please find my answer here for more details: [How to get updated copy state of azure blob when using blob StartCopyAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965876/how-to-get-updated-copy-state-of-azure-blob-when-using-blob-startcopyasync)

Comment: If you await the async method it will start on the next line when the awaited me hot is finished. You don’t need to track the state.

Comment: @KoenvanderLinden Your statement is true for all async methods, but `StartCopyAsync` is a special method, when it finishes successfully, a copy operation is started on Azure Storage sever side. Therefore, we need to periodically invoke another API to fetch blob copy state from server side. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to await `async` methods. StartCopyAsync fails, because you run a delete file call at the same time. Try using `await` or `Result` property.

```
var cred = new StorageCredentials("storageName", "Key");
var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = client.GetContainerReference("containerName");
CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("folder/test.jpg");

//this doesn't work
await sourceBlob.StartCopyAsync(new Uri("destination url"));
//this works
await sourceBlob.DeleteAsync();
```

Code not tested, but should give you a general idea.

Comment: You should switch the source and destionation params. As the StartCopy should be called on the destionation blob.